# OS Symlinks with same inode

Tags: linux, file, operating-system, symlink

I want to know how we can have 2 symlinks (not 2 regular files or hardlink and symlink but 2 symlinks) with the same inode and the same inode point. I tried a lot of combination of hardlinks and symlinks and regular files, I can have two files with same inode and the same inode point  but they aren't both of them symlinks.

N.B: I use the os library under python3 to get all the informations and "os.path.islink" for knowing if it's a symlink, and "os.stat" "os.lstat"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: you can't have 2 symlinks with the same inode, but they can of course refer to the same inode.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about the design of Linux. Try SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The way you make two names point to the same inode is with the `link()` system call. But if the source file is a symlink, this will follow it to its target, it won't make the new name refer to the same inode as the symlink.

Comment: So unless you manipulate the filesystem directly, there's no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, the tool you use for making hardlink does not follow the symlink you are trying to link. On command line, you can do it like this, for example:

```
cp -l -P symlink1 symlink2
```

These options mean:

```
   -l, --link
          hard link files instead of copying
   -P, --no-dereference
          never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
```

In Python, [starting from version 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.link), you can do the following:

```
os.link ("symlink1", "symlink2", follow_symlinks = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all of your answers but actually I solved the problem, I can have two files with the same inodes and the same inodes point,

I needed to create the hardlink of the symlink of a file (file f1 as example)

```
ln symlinkf1 hardlink_ofsymlinkf1
```

Then I get inode_symlink1 = inode_hardlink_ofsymlinkf1 (1)

and inodepoint_symlinkf1 = inodepoint_hardlink_ofsymlinkf1 (2)

but (1) =/= (2)

And this works well only in Linux where I get both of the files as softlinks (with os.islink(file_name)=True), and weirdly it doesn't work on Mac OS.